# What does following code means int val = str.charAt(i) - 'a';?

Tags: string, char

The code is taken from career cup book

```
public static boolean isUniqueChars(String str)  {

    if (str.length() > 256) {
        return false;`
    }

    int checker = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        int val = str.charAt(i) - 'a';
        if ((checker & (1 << val)) > 0) return false;
        checker |= (1 << val);
    }
    return true;
}
```

---

Thank you for explanation and I am not sure what do I get. Lets look at the following code-

```
public class ConvertAscii {

    public static void main(String args[]){
        String str ="Hello How are you";
        int i =0;
        for(i=0;i<str.length();i++){
            System.out.println(str.charAt(i)-'a');
        }
    }

}
```

It gives me following output-

-24
12
32
34

etc

Also as in the above example we have

For example if str is "fbhsdsbfid" and i is 4 then val is equal to 3. What does subtracting ascii value of character 'a' from another character results in? Please explain more

Comment: Please add a tag indicating what language this is. (Is it Java?) Also, CareerCup is a publisher; you might want to specify which of their books you're referring to. (The question is 4 years old and the OP hasn't been on the site recently. Perhaps someone else who's sure what language this is can add a tag.)

Answer (score 0):

It takes the character which is at index `i` in `str` and substracts the ASCII value of the character 'a'.

For example if `str` is "fbhsdsbfid" and `i` is 4 then `val` is equal to 3.

Comment: int val = str.charAt(i) - 'a';   Its basically performing subtraction of '**ascii number**' of char at index **i** in String '**str**' **with** ascii number of char '**a**'

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question for index i = 4, the character at index 4 is 'd' and it's corresponding ASCII value is 64.

The ASCII value of 'a' is 61.Therefore, str.charAt(i) - 'a' gives 64 - 61 = 3.